# Need to call Two APIs In Loop using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of ssn number and I have two api list in which I need to pass ssn number as request json so I need to call both api inside ssn loop so I pass ssn to json request during call both api but code is not work properly both api call at a time simulteniously, Where I need to call both api one by one.

Both API details and code are as follow

**My Code:**

```
let ssn = [460458524, 637625452, 453311896, 635285187, 455791630, 642348377, 463590491, 450730278, 641201851, 379965491];
async function getCRCDetails() {
  ssn.forEach(function (item) {
    if(item){
    let CBCOptions = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'url': 'https://loanboard.houstondirectauto.com/api/Report',
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': 'ci_session=udmojmlc5tfl3epbrmtvgu6nao2f031p'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "token": loantoken,
        "action": "CBCReport",
        "variables": {
          ssn: item
        }
      })
    }
 request(CBCOptions, function (error, response) {
        console.log(item);
        console.log("CBCOPtion ", CBCOptions);
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        result = (JSON.parse(response.body));
        console.log("Result =", result);
        CRCReport.push(result);
      })
 let EmployerInfoOptions = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'https://loanboard.houstondirectauto.com/api/Report',
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Cookie': 'ci_session=udmojmlc5tfl3epbrmtvgu6nao2f031p'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "token": loantoken,
          "action": "getEmployerInfo",
          "variables": {
            ssn: item
          }
        })
      }
 request(EmployerInfoOptions, function (error, response) {
       console.log(response.body);

      })

}
```

Here I need to call API request one by one.Anyone Guide me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer use async await method for this situation
you need install and require `async` and `request-promise`
after that :

```
const request = require("request-promise");
const async = require("async");
let ssn = [460458524, 637625452, 453311896, 635285187, 455791630, 642348377, 463590491, 450730278, 641201851, 379965491];

async function getCRCDetails() {
  //like a forEache
  async.eachSeries(ssn, async (item) => {
      let CBCOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://loanboard.houstondirectauto.com/api/Report",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Cookie: "ci_session=udmojmlc5tfl3epbrmtvgu6nao2f031p",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          token: loantoken,
          action: "CBCReport",
          variables: {
            ssn: item,
          },
        }),
      };
      let EmployerInfoOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://loanboard.houstondirectauto.com/api/Report",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Cookie: "ci_session=udmojmlc5tfl3epbrmtvgu6nao2f031p",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          token: loantoken,
          action: "getEmployerInfo",
          variables: {
            ssn: item,
          },
        }),
      };
      try {
        let resultCBCOptions = await request(CBCOptions);
        let EmployerInfoOptions = await request(EmployerInfoOptions);
        console.log(resultCBCOptions)
        console.log(EmployerInfoOptions)
        //do pushing resultCBCOptions
        //do pushing EmployerInfoOptions
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    () => {
      console.log("finished");
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Node the request methods that you are using are asynchronous. Meaning the runner (server) that runs the code does not wait for the request to finish and just continues to execute the next lines.

One thing that you can do is,

```
request.post(params).on("response", function(response) {
//....Do stuff with your data you recieve
// Make the next call here
request.post(params).on("response"), function() {
// Here you will have the second call's results
}
})
```

This ensures that both the API calls happen in order and only after the first one finishes.

#### Note:

The `request` library that you are using has been deprecated back in 2020. See https://github.com/request/request Hence, I would suggest you use other libraries like the standard `https` or `http` library that is shipped with node or you can use `axios`.

Comment: This code I applied not request is not work in Order.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a forEach loop without awaiting the results, you'll execute them all at the same time. Moreover, request library is kind of old and you need to convert its functions to return a promise.

Here's how I would do it.

```
const ssn = [1,2,3,4];

function download(item) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let options = {}; // construct your request
        request(options, function (error, response) {
            if(error) {
                return reject(error);
            }
            resolve(response);
        })      
    }
}

ssn = ssn.map(async function(item) {
    let res = await download(item);
    // process the result
    return res;
});
```

You can also use the Bluebird library or get another client library such as got or axios.